# SQL Server stored procedure return output

Tags: sql, sql-server

My stored procedure produces the output as shown below. Is there a way to return the log?

```
(7 Zeilen betroffen)

(7 Zeilen betroffen)

(7 Zeilen betroffen)

(4 Zeilen betroffen)

(14 Zeilen betroffen)

(7 Zeilen betroffen)

(24 Zeilen betroffen)

(1 Zeile betroffen)

(0 Zeilen betroffen)

(0 Zeilen betroffen)

(5 Zeilen betroffen)

(0 Zeilen betroffen)

(6 Zeilen betroffen)

(2 Zeilen betroffen)

(2 Zeilen betroffen)
```

SQL Server Management Studio produces this script when running the procedure:

```
USE [Server]
GO

DECLARE @return_value int

EXEC    @return_value = [dbo].[script]

SELECT  'Return Value' = @return_value
GO
```

Is there a way to get the same log in the return value?
And obviously changing the returnType to varchar

Comment: If you need things like this logged, why not simply write the results of the individual operations to a table? You can always see rowcount results by using `@@RowCount`. Other than that, @return_value is basically just a way to see whether or not a procedure throws an error or not.

Comment: That just looks like a German-localized version of the `(x row(s) affected)` message produced by Management Studio. The procedure isn't (directly) producing that message (and so it cannot be captured directly on the server), it's just shown as a result of `NOCOUNT` being `OFF`.

Comment: @SchmitzIT can i just add `return @@RowCount`  to the end of my procedure?

Comment: In truth, *normally* you would have `NOCOUNT` set to `ON` in a procedure as (some) languages infer things like `(7 rows(s) affected)` as a result set; so you wouldn't get that message anyway.

Comment: `RETURN` is *meant* to be used to denote the success of a procedure, @0brine, `0` for success, anything else for failure. I would suggest using an `OUTPUT` parameter.

Comment: @0brine - No. @@RowCount changes per codeblock, so you'd only see the latest value. If you want things logged, after every execution, you'd log it. Ie. `UPDATE x SET y=z INSERT INTO myLog.Log 'Updated + ' @@Rowcount + ' rows'`. Obviously you'd want to add more details (better description, timestamp, etc).

Answer (score 1):

If you want a return with procedure you should use output;

As a sample;

```
create procedure spgetgenders_r
@gender nvarchar(20), 
@workercount int output
AS 
BEGIN 
Select @workercount = count (IDNumber)
from TblWorkers where TblWorkers.Gender = @gender
END
```

We are giving nvarchar to procedure and getting int output.

[gender = input]
[workercount = output]

When we execute this stored procedure we are using int variable to store that output. Execution code below.

```
declare @workertotal int 
execute spgetgenders_r 'Man', 
@workertotal output
print @workertotal
```

We can use return option;

```
create procedure spgetworkestotal2
as begin 
return (select count(IDNumber) from TblWorkers)
end
```

We can execute like this.

```
declare @total int 
execute @total = spgetworkestotal2
print @total
```

We can use more than one return in stored procedure, we should write between "begin" and "end".